# Making tooltip plug-in follow mouse instead of static position

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, mousemove, jquery-tooltip

I'm using this tooltip plug-in:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex5/balloontooltip.htm

It's very useful and highly customizable because you can use the HTML elements that you defined as tooltips and very quick to init; you only have to define the id of the element that you want to use as a tooltip in the trigger element's rel property.

I am using a lot of different divs so this really helps me a lot.

There was just a little problem. I want it to follow the mouse not have static position.

I've added something at the end:

```
$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
    amouseX = e.pageX - 30;
    amouseY = e.pageY + 20;
    $(".tooltip").css({ left: amouseX + "px", top: amouseY + "px" });
});
```

and this to the displayballoontip(obj, e)

```
dropmenuobj.x = amouseX
dropmenuobj.y = amouseY
```

and changed every visibility:hidden to display:none in the code. because after i've added these, tooltip caused some scrolling issues in browser display:none fixed them.

but now I have some problems with internet explorer. It does not work well in many different ways like: i can see tooltip moving from somewhere to mouse on the screen, tooltips don't disappear immediately onmouseout.

here is the code with everything i've done:

```
var disappeardelay=0  //tooltip disappear delay (in miliseconds)
var verticaloffset=0 //vertical offset of tooltip from anchor link, if any
var enablearrowhead=0 //0 or 1, to disable or enable the arrow image
var arrowheadimg=["arrowdown.gif", "arrowup.gif"] //path to down and up arrow images
var arrowheadheight=11 //height of arrow image (amount to reveal)

/////No further editting needed
var ie=document.all
var ns6=document.getElementById&&!document.all
verticaloffset=(enablearrowhead)? verticaloffset+arrowheadheight : verticaloffset

function getposOffset(what, offsettype){
var totaloffset=(offsettype=="left")? what.offsetLeft : what.offsetTop;
var parentEl=what.offsetParent;
while (parentEl!=null){
totaloffset=(offsettype=="left")? totaloffset+parentEl.offsetLeft : totaloffset+parentEl.offsetTop;
parentEl=parentEl.offsetParent;
}
return totaloffset;
}

function showhide(obj, e){
//dropmenuobj.style.left=dropmenuobj.style.top="-500px"
if (e.type=="mouseover")
obj.display="block"
}

function iecompattest(){
return (document.compatMode && document.compatMode!="BackCompat")? document.documentElement : document.body
}

function clearbrowseredge(obj, whichedge){
if (whichedge=="rightedge"){
edgeoffsetx=0
var windowedge=ie && !window.opera? iecompattest().scrollLeft+iecompattest().clientWidth-15 : window.pageXOffset+window.innerWidth-15
dropmenuobj.contentmeasure=dropmenuobj.offsetWidth
if (windowedge-dropmenuobj.x < dropmenuobj.contentmeasure)
edgeoffsetx=dropmenuobj.contentmeasure-obj.offsetWidth
if (dropmenuobj.x-edgeoffsetx+dropmenuobj.contentmeasure>windowedge)
edgeoffsetx=dropmenuobj.x-windowedge+dropmenuobj.contentmeasure
return edgeoffsetx
}
else{
edgeoffsety=0
var topedge=ie && !window.opera? iecompattest().scrollTop : window.pageYOffset
var windowedge=ie && !window.opera? iecompattest().scrollTop+iecompattest().clientHeight-15 : window.pageYOffset+window.innerHeight-18
dropmenuobj.contentmeasure=dropmenuobj.offsetHeight
if (windowedge-dropmenuobj.y < dropmenuobj.contentmeasure) //move up?
edgeoffsety=dropmenuobj.contentmeasure+obj.offsetHeight+(verticaloffset*2)
return edgeoffsety
}
}

function displayballoontip(obj, e){ //main ballooon tooltip function
if (window.event) event.cancelBubble=true
else if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation()
if (typeof dropmenuobj!="undefined") //hide previous tooltip?
dropmenuobj.style.display="none"
clearhidemenu()
obj.onmouseout=delayhidemenu
dropmenuobj=document.getElementById(obj.getAttribute("rel"))
showhide(dropmenuobj.style, e)
dropmenuobj.x = amouseX
dropmenuobj.y = amouseY
dropmenuobj.style.left=dropmenuobj.x-clearbrowseredge(obj, "rightedge")+"px"
dropmenuobj.style.top=dropmenuobj.y-clearbrowseredge(obj, "bottomedge")+obj.offsetHeight+"px"
if (enablearrowhead)
displaytiparrow()
}

function displaytiparrow(){ //function to display optional arrow image associated with tooltip
tiparrow=document.getElementById("arrowhead")
tiparrow.src=(edgeoffsety!=0)? arrowheadimg[0] : arrowheadimg[1]
var ieshadowwidth=(dropmenuobj.filters && dropmenuobj.filters[0])? dropmenuobj.filters[0].Strength-1 : 0
//modify "left" value depending on whether there's no room on right edge of browser to display it, respectively
tiparrow.style.left=(edgeoffsetx!=0)? parseInt(dropmenuobj.style.left)+dropmenuobj.offsetWidth-tiparrow.offsetWidth-10+"px" : parseInt(dropmenuobj.style.left)+5+"px"
//modify "top" value depending on whether there's no room on right edge of browser to display it, respectively
tiparrow.style.top=(edgeoffsety!=0)? parseInt(dropmenuobj.style.top)+dropmenuobj.offsetHeight-tiparrow.offsetHeight-ieshadowwidth+arrowheadheight+"px" : parseInt(dropmenuobj.style.top)-arrowheadheight+"px"
tiparrow.style.display="block"
}

function delayhidemenu(){
delayhide=setTimeout("dropmenuobj.style.display='none';  if (enablearrowhead) tiparrow.style.display='none'",disappeardelay)
}

function clearhidemenu(){
if (typeof delayhide!="undefined")
clearTimeout(delayhide)
}

function reltoelement(linkobj){ //tests if a link has "rel" defined and it's the ID of an element on page
var relvalue=linkobj.getAttribute("rel")
return (relvalue!=null && relvalue!="" && document.getElementById(relvalue)!=null && document.getElementById(relvalue).className=="tooltip")? true : false
}

function initalizetooltip(){
var all_links=document.getElementsByTagName("a")
if (enablearrowhead){
tiparrow=document.createElement("img")
tiparrow.setAttribute("src", arrowheadimg[0])
tiparrow.setAttribute("id", "arrowhead")
document.body.appendChild(tiparrow)
}
for (var i=0; i<all_links.length; i++){
if (reltoelement(all_links[i])){ //if link has "rel" defined and it's the ID of an element on page
all_links[i].onmouseover=function(e){
var evtobj=window.event? window.event : e
displayballoontip(this, evtobj)
}
all_links[i].onmouseout=delayhidemenu
}
}
}

if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", initalizetooltip, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", initalizetooltip)
else if (document.getElementById)
window.onload=initalizetooltip

$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
    amouseX = e.pageX - 30;
    amouseY = e.pageY + 20;
    $(".tooltip").css({ left: amouseX + "px", top: amouseY + "px" });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a function on mouse move event 
you can use that to update the positions

http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick working example:

**EDIT little improvement:**

```
<html>
<head>

<script>

var divName = 'follower'; 
var offX = 15;
var offY = 15;     

function mouseX(evt) {

    if (!evt) evt = window.event; 
    if (evt.pageX) {

        return evt.pageX; 

    }
    else if (evt.clientX) {

        return evt.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ?  document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);

    }
    else {

        return 0;

    }

}

function mouseY(evt) {

    if (!evt) {

        evt = window.event; 
        if (evt.pageY) {

            return evt.pageY; 

        }

    }
    else if (evt.clientY) {

        return evt.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop); 

    }
    else {

        return 0;

    }

}

function follow(evt) {

    if (document.getElementById) {

        var obj = document.getElementById(divName).style; obj.visibility = 'visible';
        obj.left = (parseInt(mouseX(evt))+offX) + 'px';
        obj.top = (parseInt(mouseY(evt))+offY) + 'px';

    }

}

</script>

<style>

#follower {
    position:absolute; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index:999; 
    width:100px; 
    height:100px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    color: #000;
} 

.item {

    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;

}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="item" onclick="follow(event); document.onmousemove = follow;">
    click me for tooltip
</div>

<div id="follower">  
Hey I am a shadow!
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i can't figure out how to implement this to my plug-in and i can't use getElementById because i've got a lot of divs prepared to show tooltips but i can use getElementByClass maybe?

Comment: You can have only one DIV for tooltips and update it's innerHTML with message for that item dynamicaly. And you can use getElementById in any way just adjust your code for that. This is pure java script solution I don't like jquery :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
    amouseX = e.pageX - 30;
    amouseY = e.pageY + 20;
    $(".tooltip").css({ left: amouseX + "px", top: amouseY + "px" });
});
```

this makes tooltip move with mouse but there are some problems. I've edited the question for explaining the problems and put the code's last status.